# How to find a specific warning in the whole project

Tags: android, android-studio, warnings

Is there a way to search a specific warning in the whole project?

e.g. I have this warning in one of my LinearLayouts:

> Set android:baselineAligned="false" on this element for better
>   performance

and I want to check if there are any similar warnings in other LinearLayouts in my XMLs. I know about `Analyze -> Inspect Code` but it doesn't help me in this situation and in this kind of problem.

How can I find them?

Comment: @RumitPatel: Searching **where**  for **what** dued? :))

Comment: I meant I have same issue.

Comment: @RumitPatel: You removed your first comment and I answered the air :)) If you didn't find the answer yet you can check [Stanislav Bondar's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53911562/6444297). It worked for me.

Comment: yeh true. I checked it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no filters but you can select custom scope in your case is `xml` folder as 
`file[app]:src/main/res/layout/*`

Or you can `Run Inspection by Name ...` and this should be -> Missing baselineAligned attribute

Comment: I didn't understand the second part of your answer. What does `by Name ...` mean?

Comment: This is option in Analyze .Right click on App folder -> Analyze -> Run Inspection by Name ...

Comment: @AlirezaNoorali   By name inspecting code with allowed attribute